# Class not found exception - oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver

Tags: java, database, oracle, jdbc, database-connection

I'm trying to execute the below program but i'm getting -

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
```

exception. Please suggest a fix. I'm new to java.
I'm basically trying to read a value from T_Profile table of the DB and print the same.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    String addr = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@hostName:1521:serviceName";
    String un = "username";
    String pw = "password";
    Connection con = null;
    try
    {
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(addr,un,pw);
        Statement stat = con.createStatement();
        String query = "select * from schema.T_PROFILE where profile_id = 100292";
        ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery(query);
        while(rs.next())
        {
            String Profile_id = rs.getString(1);
            System.out.println(Profile_id);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
    System.out.println(e);  
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to have Oracle's jdbc jar file - you can get it from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/index-091264.html

Comment: I have downloaded ojdbc6. Should I add this?
Or the ones present at C:\app\sjois\product\11.2.0\client_1\jdbc\lib ?

Comment: I don't know what is your C: drive, but if is not finding the class, then you need to add it.   Is your project being built using maven?  Best way in that case is to include it as a dependency on your Pom file; the top of that page links to details for the maven repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `ojdbc14.jar` file in your project `lib` folder

Comment: I have downloaded ojdbc6. Should I add this? Or the ones present at C:\app\sjois\product\11.2.0\client_1\jdbc\lib ?

Comment: add the one present in `C:\app\sjois\product\11.2.0\client_1\jdbc\lib`

Answer (score 0):

add .jar file in the library.
you can get it from here
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/apps-tech/jdbc-112010-090769.html